# Does Hamcrest contain test runner or should I use a runner from another framework?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I've found only Hamcrest assertions in Hamcrest project.

Tests in the applications I saw are run with JUnit runner.

Is there a way to run tests with  Hamcrest or is Hamcrest not for this?

Answer (score 3):

Hamcrest is not a testing framework, it is an assertions library which tries to make tests more readable.

JUnit 4 (and Hamcrest itself) provides an `assertThat()` method which accepts a Hamcrest matcher, for example:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ATest {
    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        String expected = "...";

        String actual = doSomething();

        assertThat(actual, is(expected));

    }
}
```

So, a typical usage pattern is:

- Run your tests with a JUnit runner
- Use Hamcrest's matchers to assert the success (or otherwise) of your tests

More details on Hamcrest [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamcrest) and on its use alongside JUnit [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Hamcrest/article.html#hamcrestoverview).

Comment: Thanks, and is it hamcrest?  "Hamcrest matchers for testing Java beans", but not hamcrest package "com.google.code.bean-matchers".
 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.bean-matchers/bean-matchers/0.11

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking in that last comment. This: "com.google.code.bean-matchers" was not mentioned in the original question so I can't work out what you are trying to ask in your last comment.